# Meaning of "passing surmisal" in a poem by Francis Thompson

Tags: phrase-meaning, poetry

*To a Snowflake* by [Francis Thompson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Thompson):

> What heart could have thought you? --
>   Past our devisal
>   (O filigree petal!)
>   Fashioned so purely,
>   Fragilely, surely,
>   From what Paradisal
>   Imagineless metal,
>   Too costly for cost?
>   Who hammered you, wrought you,
>   From argentine vapor? --
>   "God was my shaper.
>   **Passing surmisal**,
>   He hammered, He wrought me,
>   From curled silver vapor,
>   To lust of His mind --
>   Thou could'st not have thought me!
>   So purely, so palely,
>   Tinily, surely,
>   Mightily, frailly,
>   Insculped and embossed,
>   With His hammer of wind,
>   And His graver of frost

Is the meaning of the bolded phrase "this is beyond our (or my) guessing"?
"You (mere people) are unable to guess how he hammered and wrought me"?

I looked up the meaning of "surmisal" in dictionaries but am not sure still.

From Wiktionary:

> 1. Surmisal (noun): Thought, imagination, or conjecture, which may be based upon feeble or scanty evidence; suspicion; guess.
> 2. Reflection; thought; posit.

Could it mean "the God was passing his surmisal while he hammered and wrought me"? I mean, like a decision is *passed* by a court?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's Lit Crit

Comment: @FumbleFingers - it has nothing to do with Lit Crit. I do not understand the basic meaning of "passing surmisal". Is it "beyond surmisal" or is it "the God was passing his surmisal while he wrought me"?

Comment: OED says of ***surmisal*** that it's a "now rare" variant of ***surmise***. Which *could* refer to any of several "now obsolete" definitions for the latter, given we're looking at a *poem* written over 150 years ago. But my guess is that line is what we might still convey today as ***Just a passing thought...*** In context I'd say it means the *snowflake* was formed by God in a moment of whimsy, but maybe it's the *poet* having a passing thought about how snowflakes are created. Or maybe it's something else. It's ***poetry**!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - ah, so it is closer to my second guess. I could not have guessed it out by myself. That's why I need this basic breakdown of possible meanings.

Comment: Well, I might be wrong in my interpretation(s), but obviously being a native speaker with a degree including Lit Crit I've got more *chance* of coming up with something credible. If we're lucky someone like StoneyB may weigh in on this one (and I fully accept *he* has far more chance of nailing such things than me!). But I hope you and I don't have a serious disagreement over whether my closevote is justified. Always bearing in mind that in situations like this *you* can't really be expected to know that at time of posting the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - thank you for your help! If the question is deemed too litcritish, I will just try my luck in poetry-related groups on Facebook, so it's not a thing to wrangle much about. (0: Of course I hope StoneyB walks by and chips in, he is great in untangling such cases of advanced-stage poetitis.

Comment: I didn't know there were "poetry-related groups on Facebook", but if you find one suitable for this specific question it'd be great if you could post a link. I don't actually *like* Facebook, but I do have an account, and I sometimes hold my nose and go there for specific purposes. FWIW, I just checked Google Books for "Passing surmisal" ***not*** followed by "he hammered", hoping someone might have discussed possible meanings. But I didn't find a single instance where I can read the actual words in context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I dislike Facebook's poetry groups, at least those I tried to read, but I don't know any other cyber-place to ask for the meaning.. If I find a good group, I'll notify you

Comment: I expect Thompson was familiar with the idea that "no two snowflakes are exactly alike". Even today, I'm not sure if that's a statistically valid "truth", but I'm guessing she was religious and may actually have thought God had a hand in making sure every snowflake *was* different. So it might be a sort of paean to her God, who's so powerful he can easily remember zillions of previous, current, and future snowflake shapes (and infallibly avoid duplication whenever he makes another one, even though he does this countless times a second, as "passing thoughts, fleeting fancies").

Comment: Just a passing surmisal - how about if whenever a question like this turns up, we settle on a standard response whereby the question is closed as LitCrit, leaving a link to a chat thread (which the system is obviously nagging us to do now! :)  That way we'd have a dedicated page for "legitimate" discussion. But I don't suppose TPTB here on SO would really approve in the long run, if ELL became a sort of "portal" to a poetry-related discussion-based "sub-site". Still, it's an idea. Should we maybe raise it in meta?

Comment: Oh. I've just realised why you put up a slightly different interpretation. You're parsing ***passing*** as if it means ***surpassing** [understanding]* - which could then be adjectivally applied to how God hammered and worked the snowflake (i.e. - the way that God makes snowflakes "passeth all understanding"). Yeah, that's a perfectly credible interpretation, and I don't necessarily believe it's always *meaningful* to try and select a single "correct" meaning. Sometimes we find things in Shakespeare that he couldn't possibly have intended/foreseen.

Comment: I would think it meant something like "beyond human ken", surpassing our ability to imagine or conjecture how...

Comment: I see no reason to close a question as LitCrit if the question is about the literal meaning of a word or phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You understand this correctly: *passing surmisal* means 'beyond (the ability of our merely human minds to) conjecture'.

As you have probably learned from dictionaries, *surmisal* is a rare noun form of *surmise*, as (even rarer) *devisal* is of *devise*. Thompson's poetry seems to me to be driven mostly by auditory qualities, and his choice of these words was probably prompted more by the mostly amphibrachal meter and the happy rhyme with *Paradisal* than by his pre-Raphaelite fondness for preciosity.